# Ubuntu 20.04 hangs after sent to Suspend mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on Lenovo Thinkpad P1 (and using Grub to dual boot between Windows and Linux on two physically separate SSD drives).

Recently I let the system install some updates. After the updates, I'm not able to send the machine to Suspend mode. I am not using the lid to suspend it since I use external monitors. I tried the UI command and also command line `systemctl suspend`. Both don't work:

- screen goes blank
- the laptop light on the power button is still on
- I hear the fan running
- I can't wake the system
- I have to hard reset the system by pressing the power button for 5 seconds

What could be wrong? Which logs should I look first? What to search for in the logs?

Comment: Check if the update completed, and if there are broken packages, either using the *Synaptic Package Manager*, https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/ , or from terminal, https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nothing seems to be broken.

Comment: I had to check that in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` there was the correct UUID for the swap partition (I had more than one disk and swap partition)

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this by changing the NVIDIA video driver.

Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

I switched from `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` to `nvidia-driver-5120`, and all works now.

Comment: Hmm. I've had Nvidia selected for the longest time but this still happens every now and then. It's really frustrating as a developer 

Answer (score 0):

I ve personally fixed this issue just by installing this :

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings nvidia-prime
```

Maybe it would help someone